# Converting polygon to raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

This seems like a simple question but I can't solve this issue.

I want to convert the following Polygons (see Image) into Raster using QGIS and used the Tools 'rasterize' from QGIS and SAGA as well as GRASS `v.to.raster`. They all give me the same result:

[image]

I want the raster to be only under the individual Polygons.
The problem is that I used the Polygon Layer as Output extent of the tool. But what settings can I use so that the raster is only under the polygon?

I also tried to clip this result with the tool "Clip raster by mask layer" but nothing happened. I got a new raster layer with the exact same extent.

Comment: I could be wrong but isnt a raster always a rectangle? Areas with no polygon should have no-data as value (and not symbolized / transparent, see Transparency tab under Layer properties)  . Which no-data settings are you using when rasterizing the polygons?

Comment: Yes, ok you are right. I was confused with the black color that represent the noData cells. The tools work fine actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not understand what you mean by the raster is under the polygon? If you mean that you want the black color to go away, try the "Convert Map to Raster" from the "Processing Toolbox". You have an option to make the background transparent.

[image]

Comment: Yes I was confused with the black color that represent the no-data cells. I thought the conversion doesn't work.